# Is there a sense of "caravanserai" which includes an elaborate transportation - such as of a circus?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The OED lists only one non-metaphorical sense of the word ***caravanserai*** - (from *caravan* - etymology Persian).

***A kind of inn in Eastern countries where caravans put up, being a large quadrangular building with a spacious court in the middle.***

This is endorsed by *Wikipedia* which provides much the same meaning.

However I have most often heard ***caravanserai*** used to describe a motley transportantion on a number of vehicles - such as of a circus moving from one place to the next. Of course a *caravan* was originally: *A company of merchants, pilgrims, or others, in the East or northern Africa, travelling together for the sake of security, esp. through the desert.* So the notion of transportation was inherent to the word's beginnings. Hence I am puzzled by the idea of *caravanserai* being a fixed building or settlement.

**Consider the following use - which accords entirely with the way I have most often heard the word used in Britain- from *Six Wives: the Queens of Henry VIII* by David Starkey (London 2003) p.230.**

*It was in any case a day of upheaval at Court as it was the beginning of the Progress. The whole courtly  apparatus of 'portable magnificence' - the tapestries and cushions, jewels and plate, household utensils and the King's own clothes, bedding and travelling library, medicine chest and personal petty-cash - had been packed into their special bags, boxes and chests and loaded on to carts. The carts had been covered with bear hides to protect them against the elements **and the great caravanserai of the Court** stood ready to depart from Greenwich to the first port of call of the Progress: Waltham Abbey in Essex.*

This seems to refer, as I would have expected, to the travelling body rather than to anything fixed.

Comment: A Google search for Caravanserai meaning gave the two meanings you have provided as definitions. I would guess that using the word caravan seemed to plain for the author, or perhaps he wanted to suggest that it seemed as though the whole establishment, building included, was packed up ready to move.

Comment: @Peter Yes. And that is the way I recall it being used nowadays - an establishment packed up and ready to move, or moving. But I am puzzled as to why the dictionaries do not reflect this.

Comment: No, a caravsnsessai is a fixed place, the usage you suggest is a figurative one ( the whole Court is described as a caravanserai). By their original nature caravanserais were places with high walls and a big strong door where to rest but especially to protect the travelling  caravans from being stolen to robbed.

Comment: 1590s, carvanzara, "Eastern inn (with a large central court) catering to caravans," ultimately from Persian karwan-sarai, ***from karwan (see caravan) + sara'i "palace, mansion; inn,"***

Comment: By 'The OED lists only one non-metaphorical sense of the word X' do you mean that it gives n senses, marking (n - 1) of them 'metaphorical', or is this your assessment?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Only two senses of *caravanserai* are listed - a and b. The first, a,  is the one I quote in the question, with examples from 1599 to 1854;  b is marked "*transferred* and *figurative*" with only three examples from 1760 to 1864. They speak of such things as a man whose mind is a *caravansera of opinions*. So where n = 2, n-1=1. Does that convince you?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravanserai) gives the etymology of 'caravanserai': << Caravanserai: 
The word کاروانسرای kārvānsarāy is a Persian compound word combining kārvān "caravan" with sarāy "palace", "building with enclosed courts". >> Entered the English Lexicon in the 1590s (Etymon).  [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/caravanserai) adds a back-transferred, metonymic sense for the English term: << Caravanserai: ... (2) A group of people travelling together; a caravan >>.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well done! Why don't you supply the Lexico entry as an answer? I think it proves my point toi some extent.  But is it *metonymy*? Yes, I suppose if one says "the village was on the beach, helping the landing of the boats*, then that is equivalent to the *caravanserai being assembled in the Babylon Hotel*. But my own sense is that a caravanserai is as much about a motley collection of goods as well as people.

Comment: Metonymy is very broadly scoped 'We use B to invoke A which is somehow related'. 'Boil the kettle' for 'boil the water in the kettle'. 'Caravanserai' = 'entourage visiting a caravanserai' = 'similar sort of entourage'. // But the etymology is basic reference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That figurative use in the OED about a "man's mind being a caravanserai of opinions" seems to me to suggest lots of bits and pieces. Unless it means a guy whose mind is made up of the opinions of a *pot pourri* of people.

Comment: The initial metonymy (in English) was from the 'caravan-otel' sense 'back' to the caravan sense. The OED example is obviously a further metaphorical broadening. It's not an idiom, and not transparent, so one has to guess. Bits and pieces? Very probably. A fairly coherent train of thought/s? Probably. Colourful, and interesting in a barren landscape? Hidebound, hard to redirect? Snappy?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My guess from all this is that *caravanserai* has been employed variously by writers with only a loose sense of its meaning. Clearly in Starky's mind is the idea of a pile of household effects as well as perhaps servants. A more accurate word for him to have employed may have been *caravan* - but the problem with that is that in modern English it has come to mean something quite different.

Comment: 'Circus' has the pejorative sense invoking chaos, a broadening of 1869 if  [Etymon](https://www.etymonline.com/word/circus) gets it right.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course circus transportation does involve caravans (in the modern sense) - so there is a clear connection there. I would suggest that *caravanserai* has acquired a meaning in modern English, beyond the idea of a fixed building that receives travellers - and that Starkey's use demonstrates that.

Comment: I've only found one relevant example, an obvious purloining of the term by ArtsMidwest, among 30 on 3 random pages (after p5 to get rid of some of the definitions) on Google. I'd say it's a rare metaphor. But do Lexico, Wiktionary, CD, M-W, Macmillan, Webster's, AHD, Wiktionary even ... list the metaphorical broadening &/or have an example sentence showing it?

Comment: @WS2 "That figurative use in the OED about a "man's mind being a caravanserai of opinions" seems to me to suggest lots of bits and pieces." To me, it is about intransigence . Once inside, opinions are pretty much unassailable. A caravanserai is a fortification first and foremost. The potential eclecticism lends a nice parallel, though.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find a time period in which  *caravanserai* expanded in meaning from a structure (palace, hotel, inn, place where caravans were loaded, corral, etc.) to travelling people (or people and their paraphernalia,  sometimes including their vehicles) who resembled a caravanserai in some figurative way.

> After this first pause at Jerusalem, the **caravanserai** got under
> way again and set out on a long journey through all the scenes of the
> Old Testament, the storied deserts and ruins of Syria, not much less
> ancient to the view and much less articulate than now. This was in the year 387, two years after their departure from Rome. [Margaret
> Oliphant; *The Makers of Modern Rome*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Delphi_Works_of_Margaret_Oliphant_with_C/PHcyBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=After%20this%20first%20pause%20at%20Jerusalem,%20the%20caravanserai%20got%20under%20way%20again%20and%20set%20out%20on%20a%20long%20journey%20through%20all%20the%20scenes%20of%20the%20Old%20Testament,%20the%20storied%20deserts%20and%20ruins%20of%20Syria,%20not%20much%20less%20ancient%20to%20the%20view%20and%20much%20less%20articulate%20than%20now.&pg=PT8335&printsec=frontcover) (1895)

This early mention of a *travelling caravanserai* is a curious: a stationary "caravanserai" that moves: a "travelling hotel":

> An ocean trip to-day is usually a very conventional affair. Travelling
> hotels—which the big liners boastfully claim to be—do not lend
> themselves to the spirit of a romance supposed to be attached to Old
> Ocean.
> Diligent search will, however, reveal a certain amount of
> genuine romance even on a **travelling caravanserai**. In order to
> find the romance, a process of elimination must be resorted to. [W. B.
> Northrop; "Life on a Liner: The Romance and Realism of an Ocean
> Voyage"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Sketch/uH84AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22travelling%20caravanserai%22&pg=PA378&printsec=frontcover)  (1903)

> No wonder that when ladies went on a visit in those days they went on
> "a round of them." The roads must have shown a lively aspect under
> one of these perambulations. A country call must have assumed the
> proportions of a **travelling caravanserai**.  [W. O. Tristram;
> *Moated Houses*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Moated_Houses/yyRsAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22travelling%20caravanserai%22&pg=PA317&printsec=frontcover) (1910)

---

I believe the OP's  *great caravanserai of the Court* is more likely this figurative use of *caravanserai* than the literal one. All the other 19<sup>th</sup>-century examples and definitions I found referred to something stationary.

I, too, was more familiar with the figurative meaning of something moving. Just a speculation: could it be that some authors incorrectly assumed that *caravan* was a shortened form of *caravanserai* and that a caravanserai could therefore travel?

> There are nice entries for *caravan* and *caravanserai* in [J.
> McClintock and J. Strong; *Cyclopaedia of Biblical, Theological, and
> Ecclesiastical Literature*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cyclopaedia_of_Biblical_Theological_and/YhVWAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=caravanserai%20travel&pg=PA117&printsec=frontcover) (1880)

It's curious that, as Edwin A. points out in comments, only a few dictionaries like Lexico (and I'll add the *New Oxford American Dictionary*) have a a separate meaning for "A group of people travelling together; a caravan," while the OED (last modified online in 2019) does not. The OED's three current citations for the transferred/figurative meaning are all places, even though one is a "mind" that can, obviously, move about.

**UPDATE**

The Sept. 2021 OED update added this sense for *caravanserai*:

> **2.** A group of people travelling together; a caravan (CARAVAN n. 1).
>
> 1836   *Wilson's Hist. Tales Borders* II. 230/1   On the third day,
> the caravansary reached the promised land.

Comment: Prescriptivists and descriptivists will look at these facts differently. The former will say that 'some authors **incorrectly** assumed that *caravan* was a shortened form of *caravanserai* and that a caravanserai could therefore travel', and that their using *caravanserai* as a synonym for *caravan* was simply wrong. Descriptivists will say that there are enough examples of such use of the word that it cannot be dismissed. Regardless of where on stands in that disagreement, it is probably wise to avoid so using it, as it is likely to annoy those how do know the original meaning of the word